# Will Firefox 4 support Desktop notifications

Tags: firefox

Just curious. I'm not referring to notify-osd btw, but rather to the kind of notifications you can get in chrome/chromium.

Comment: This is probably better for superuser as it's not ubuntu-specific. The feature you're looking for is "web notifications API"

Comment: @Jorge Castro cool ^^, how do I move a question (is that possible?)

Comment: Now you know. Migration is fully automatic–sort of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been [discussion about this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=573588#c28) for quite some time (this one's from 07/2010):

> Daniel, when there is a reasonable spec, we will conform.  Right now there
>   isn't, but we are working on it.  I think that the W3C just pushed the spec out
>   of webapps and into a new WG.  When that starts, we can figure out what
>   namespace this lives in.

I think they will wait until the W3C standard is finished or a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks! I think the webkit browsers should stop pushing features that aren't standard as if they are.

Comment: Yeah, it's nice to have such brand new features but at the same time this will split the community more than it needs to.